# Symfony 3 - Can't get form to be displayed on the view

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to pass a form along to a view but it wouldn't display and I get an error 500 (page loading is stopped and then, when I try to reach another page, it freezes)

I tried several tutorials including the official symfony documentation and I always get to that same point.

So please help me... (below is my code)

my controller

```
<?php
namespace siteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException;

use siteBundle\Form\ContactType;
use siteBundle\Entity\Contact;


class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function navigationAction(string $page,Request $request)
    {
        $option=array();
        if ($page=='contact')
        {
            $donnees=new Contact();
            $form=$this->createForm(ContactType::class,$donnees);
            $option['contact']=$form->createView();
        }
        return $this->render('siteBundle:Pages:'.$page.'.html.twig',$option);
    }
}
?>
```

my view

```
{% extends 'general.html.twig' %}

{% block description %}blabla{% endblock %}

{% block title %}blabla{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="container">
    <h1>Prendre Contact </h1>
    <p class="text-justify">
        <br>blabla
    </p>
    <br>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/site/img/telephone.png') }}" alt="téléphone"><br>
                <p><a href="tel:0123456789">01.23.45.67.89</a></p>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <p>
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/site/img/email.png') }}" alt="email"><br>
                <p><a href="mailto:a@b.fr">a@b.fr</a></p>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <p>
            <img class="text-center" src="{{ asset('bundles/site/img/formulaire.png') }}" alt="Formulaire"><br>
            <p>Complétez le formulaire ci-dessous</p>
        </p>
    </div>

    {% if contact is defined %}
    <div>
    {{ form_start(contact) }}
    {{ form_widget(contact) }}
    {{ form_end(contact) }}
    </div>
    {% endif %}

</div> <!-- container -->
{% endblock %}
```

thanks in advance for your help

Regards

Comment: Why in your controller you make if $page="contact". You should define a route for contact

Comment: Can you provide us the uri that you used for this page

Comment: of course : http://localhost:8000/contact

Comment: your route don't contains the param $page.please, give us the definition route for this page

Comment: navigation:
    path:     /{page}
    defaults: 
      _controller: siteBundle:Site:navigation
      page:    accueil
    requirements:
      page:    ^[a-z_]{4,}$

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the `dev` env to display the stack trace of the Exception.
You can use `/app_dev.php` for that.

Comment: the problem is i have no exception displayed. the page stops loading and nothing else happens. on the chromium developper console, it says 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Comment: Even in `dev` env?

Comment: i entered localhost:8000/app_dev.php/contact. it resulted the same.

Comment: Can you copy/paste your code instead of screenshot? It may help.

Comment: check permission cache, logs, sessions, clear cache and try to check apache2 logs

Comment: how do u check permission cache??

Comment: chmod -R 777 var/cache

Answer (score 0):

my opinion, the error in:

```
return $this->render('siteBundle:Pages:'.$page.'.html.twig',$option);
```

use:

```
return $this->render('SiteBundle:pages:'.$page.'.html.twig',$option);
```

Check your logs! /var/logs/prod.log or error.log, and you find an error message

Comment: The bundle name is siteBundle, not SiteBundle

Answer (score 0):

In you route change the key word  `controller` by `_controller`

Comment: the code with the route had a typo, i have _controller written. problem still unsolved ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help :
if i get rid of the array $option on my render line (see code below), there is absolutely no problem and the page loads fine.

```
return $this->render('siteBundle:Pages:'.$page.'.html.twig');
```

something is happening when passing the variable to the template...

Comment: Check my answer